# What is the reason behind the result of this code?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class Abc 
{
    public Abc() 
    {
        System.out.println("constructor A");
    }
}

class Bb extends Abc 
{   
    public Bb() 
    {
        super(); // Calls Abc()
        System.out.println("constructor B");
    }
}

public class X 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Bb b = new Bb();
    }
}
```

The answer is:

```
Constructor A
Constructor B
```

Can anyone tell the reason behind this?

Comment: The "reasoning" is just the normal behaviour of Java constructors.  For example: http://java67.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/how-constructor-chaining-works-in-java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a constructor of a derived class is called, it must first construct its super class. If this is not done explicitly (by specifying `super`, with or without any arguments), it is done implicitly, with the no-arguments constructor. In other words, your code is equivalent to:

```
class Abc {
    public Abc() {
        System.out.println("constructor A");
    }
}

class Bb extends Abc {   
    public Bb() {
        super(); // Calls Abc()
        System.out.println("constructor B");
    }
}

public class X {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Bb b = new Bb();
    }
}
```

Once expressed in this fashion, it's easy to see why `"constructor A"` is printed, and then `"constructor B"`.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of a sub-class (`Bb` in your case) must call a constructor of the super-class (`Abc` in your case) before executing its own constructor.

This code :

```
    public Bb() {
        System.out.println("constructor B");
    }
```

Is equivalent to :

```
    public Bb() {
        super (); // calls the super-class constructor
        System.out.println("constructor B");
    }
```

Comment: What if I don't want to call the constructor of `Abc` from `Bb` constructor?

Comment: @Junaid You have no choice. Some constructor of the super class will always be called, and if the compiler doesn't find one, your code won't compile.

Comment: @Junaid This makes sense, since a sub-class contains all the members of its super-class, and therefore it must initialize them (via a call to the super-class constructor).

Answer (score 0):

With super(), the superclass no-argument constructor is called. With super(parameter list), the superclass constructor with a matching parameter list is called.

Now if you review your code,you will get the answer.

[Refer this link for more explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)